# Unity fails to effectively split spritesheet

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, spritesheet

I'm very new to game development and I find it very difficult to split the spritesheets available at opengameart.org. All of them are kind of jumbled together without any fixed grid.

The resource I learned from always used neatly assembled sprite sheets and Unity would have no trouble in automatically splitting them. But almost all are randomly placed and Unity cannot split them.

For example:

[image]

And below is the automatic splitting in unity:

[image]

How do you guys get the sprites from such spritesheets in unity? Some guidance would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are no transparent pixels between two sprites, Unity can not detect where one sprite ends and another sprite begins.

But your spritesheet uses a fixed grid of 16x16px, so you can use the "Grid By Cell Size" slicing mode:

[image: Grid by cell size]

This will nicely slice up the 1-cell character sprites and the map tiles, but also slice up some multi-cell sprites which you might want to keep together, like the vehicles in the center-left. If you want to use those as oversized sprites, you will have to fix that by hand for each object by deleting all of the bounding boxes which cover it but one and enlarge the remaining one.